# Angular Js Tool Bar issue

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html

I am having a toolbar directive using angular material, I am using a transclude at the end of the directive and I want the transcluded element to come at the right end of the banner. But what ever I do, it wont work, its coming after the elements of the directive?

The code for template is like below.

```
<md-toolbar>
      <div class="md-toolbar-tools">

                <h2>
                        <a  ui-sref="#">Test - <span ng-bind="header.title"></span></a>    
                </h2>
          <span flex="5"></span>    
          <div ng-transclude></div>
      </div>
    </md-toolbar>
```

Please find the example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/HrtM9acp0VkzAIrVcCOQ?p=preview).   I wan to move Test123 to the right most end of the toolbar. Please help me

Comment: where you able to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this as your banner.html:

```
<md-toolbar>
  <div class="md-toolbar-tools">

            <h2>
                    <a  ui-sref="#">Test - <span ng-bind="header.title"></span></a>    
            </h2>
      <span flex="5"></span>    
      <div ng-transclude style="position:absolute;right:0;top:16"></div>
  </div>
</md-toolbar>
```

Not sure if this was what you were looking for but it does do what you asked.

Comment: Hi it does moves Test123 to the right end, but in my case i just have to move only one part of the transclusion but your example moves it completely.

Answer (score 0):

You are in the right track.
In your `banner.html` you need to modify the `<span flex="5">` to `<span flex>` this will make it expand all the way to the `right` instead of just `5` units and push everything inside the `ng-transclude` with it.

```
<md-toolbar>
  <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
    <h2>
        <a ui-sref="#">Test - <span ng-bind="header.title"></span></a>    
    </h2>
    <span flex></span>
    <div ng-transclude></div>
  </div>
</md-toolbar>
```

Also notice I cleaned up the `index.html` file so you can easily add content in between the `banner` tags.

```
<banner header-title="Title 1 Test">
    <span>Test 123</span>
</banner>
```

You can see the full [solution here](http://plnkr.co/edit/FJkKQDKVEGwNoWcOOGNx?p=preview)

If you are interested, you can find more information about the `md-toolbar` directive in the [official documentation](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/api/material.components.toolbar/directive/mdToolbar).